# Judges 5:30 - The Hebrew word for womb or damsel translated as "two". Why?

Tags: translation-philosophy, hebrew-bible, judges

Judges 5:30

One interpretation says: http://biblehub.com/esv/judges/5.htm

‘Have they not found and divided the spoil?—
A womb or two for every man;

The word Strong's #7361  ra·ḥă·mā·ṯa·yim means  damsel
The word "two" is used instead.  I understand the word before Strong's #7361  ra·ḥă·mā·ṯa·yim IS Strongs #7356 ra-ḥam   and can mean damsel or womb as well.

Why is ra·ḥă·mā·ṯa·yim translated as two?  Wouldn't the word for "two" be used if that what was meant?

Thank you
Kate

Comment: You are dealing with the Hebrew dual. For more information on the dual, please click [**here**](http://goo.gl/p6Wbwj). The reference to the Hebrew dual is on page 117 of this reference, and indicates that the dual can be translated as "two" or better "a pair of."

Comment: Thank you very much for that link.  Quick question.  Strongs # 7356  רַ֤חַם for "womb".  Shouldn't there be another (letter?) indicating "a" or "the" womb?  Sorry, I am really very new.  ... oh... maybe it doesn't need it because it's plural -- "wombs" so it doesn't need "a" or "the".

Answer (score 5):

The word *raḥamatayim* is the dual form of the word *reḥem*. This root literally means “womb” but can also mean “woman” for obvious reasons.

So Sisera’s mother is comforting herself, saying the delay is because the soldiers are collecting slave girls: “A womb or a pair-of-wombs for every man.” But in English, this reads more naturally as “A womb or two for every man,” so that’s how the translators rendered it.